# How to run a CSS animation infintely forwards

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

So I'm looking to create a really basic snow effect.

I have a keyframe animation for the flake swaying side to side and moving down the Y axis. I want the element to retain the ending values using forwards. But I also want to then loop the animation (infinite), so that it continues where it left off.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <figure class="small"></figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #184254;
}

figure {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes snowfall {
  25% {
    transform: translateX(10px) translateY(20px);
      }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(40px);
  }
}

.small {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #DFE9ED;
  -webkit-animation: snowfall 2s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}
```

http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/PwZdXB

Comment: @Danko I guess he wants to repeat the same path of the `figure`  but starting from the end point (that means below and below and below). Just not to code the whole path to the bottom of the page

Comment: @Anarion mm yes you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two animations, one to move right-left and other to make it fall.

The up to down animation will work with absolute positioning, so it will depend on body height (or its first parent with `absolute` or `relative` positioning).

```
figure {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes snowside {
 25% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
      }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes snowfall {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.small {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #DFE9ED;
  -webkit-animation: snowside 2s ease-in-out forwards infinite, snowfall 15s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPwOMY

Comment: Nice mate, plus 1 , please complement your answer with the explanation of how the up / down . works based on the height of the container.

Comment: Add vendor prefixes for [`transform`](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) and [`animation`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) for all browser support.